# Novel where sorcerer gets magic from a bottle of magic sand

Tags: story-identification, novel

I was pretty young at the time (read in the mid-90s) and don't remember much of it. It wasn't YA and I probably didn't understand a lot of the plot.

I think of it as "low fantasy"- I don't think there was magic in the world except for what the protagonist had, and even though he was a "sorcerer" he only drew power from a bottle of magic sand (or something like that) that he had mostly used up. One part that really stuck with me from the novel was that at one point he was imprisoned, unable to move at all, and he lived in his imagination for what felt like a large portion of the book.

The prison part stuck with me for a long time. He created an entire world in his mind, and IIRC it was even a story-within-the-story with him not realizing he was confined.

The "sand" part of it doesn't really stick out in my mind, and doesn't really sound right. What I remember more vividly was that different powers of spells used different amounts of the "grains" that were left. I think my memory is making them grains of sand but it could've been something else. I think he kept the bottle at the top of his tower and the climax, where he used the rest of his magic, took place there.

I rented it from the library either in 1993 or 1995-1997. The book looked fairly new. The cover was mostly white with I think a tower on it. Now that I think of it, the cover was uniquely minimalist for a fantasy book at that time. The title would have referenced magic in some way or little-me wouldn't have rented it.

Does that sound like something anyone else remembers?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? Also don't forget to take the [tour]!

Comment: Thanks! I need to think more about it to try to come up with more. Sorry I only remember these vague details- when I think of more I'm worried that I'm making things up or getting other stories mixed in my head

Comment: Hmm I thought maybe this was one of the _[Magic Goes Away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Goes_Away)_ stories but if it is it's not one I've read, the whole "bottle of magic" bit gets used several times in different parks of that universe so it might be worth a look.

Comment: I don't think I've ever read anything from that, but there's a lot in the descriptions that resonate with my memory of this- old age, mana from a physical location, even the "warlock" part. I doubt it was in the same universe but it was definitely influenced by this.

Comment: @Ash - That was my thought as well.

Comment: @Malexander - You could also look at the [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Mana) page on mana, there are a few with limited/disappearing mana there.